# Conflict in fold settings with filetype plugins

Tags: vim

I am trying to configure vim to properly fold both html and javascript. Both are working the way I'd like them to when I only open javascript files or html files, but if I open an html file, then open a javascript file, then open another html file, the indentation settings seem to have been overwritten and there is no folding in the html file.

Relevant code:

~/.vimrc

```
filetype plugin indent on
syntax on
```

~/.vim/after/ftplugin/html.vim

```
setlocal shiftwidth=2
setlocal softtabstop=2
setlocal foldmethod=indent
```

~/.vim/after/ftplugin/javascript.vim

```
setlocal foldmethod=syntax
setlocal shiftwidth=2
setlocal softtabstop=2
let foldlevelstart=1
let javaScript_fold=1
```

I am opening two files like this:

```
vim ./thing.html ./thing.js
```

Initially the html file is open and folded as I expect, then I switch to the javascript file with :b thing.js and it is also folded as i expect. Then I switch back to my html file :b thing.html and there is no folding any more. Checking :set foldmethod? shows that the foldmethod of the html file has been changed to syntax. Why is this? The problem is adding this "let javaScript_fold=1" Having this line seems to be responsible for changing my html folding method, but without it my javascript wont fold properly.